# Can`t sort by price correctly, although sorting by name works very well

Tags: angular, sorting, typescript

Trying to make this small bookstore app and wanted to add option to sort books by price and name, ascending and descending. Sorting by price occurs in very strange order, and can't find the reason for that, please if some could help and explain to me, I'm pretty new in Angular. Thank you!

Here is the source code: https://github.com/EgomortIncognitus/bookstore

Here is the code from sort-by.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sortBy'
})
export class SortByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: Array<string>, args?: any): any {

    if (array) {

      let sortField = args[0];
      let sortDirection = args[1];
      let modifier = 1;

      if (sortDirection === 'desc') {
        modifier = -1;
      }

      array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a[sortField] < b[sortField]) {
          return -1 * modifier;
        } else if (a[sortField] > b[sortField]) {
          return 1 * modifier;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      });

      return array;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: are prizes stored as numbers or maybe strings?

Comment: Typescript isn't javascript so don't tag it with javascript, the only time you should be allowed to do so is if it has something to do with transpiling typescript to javascript.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I need an explicit answer/explanation because I am bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by name and sort by number is not same in Javascript

Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting strings which will be done [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

As an example, `"9" > "800000"` but `9 < 800000`.

Comment: Sorry, but I need an explicit answer/explanation because I am bit lost. Thank you.

Comment: You want to sort numbers but what you compare are strings. You expect `"b"` to come after `"abbbbb"` but are confused about why `"9"` comes after `"800000"`. Letter wise, `"9"` is later than `"8"` and similar to the other case, when the first letter is different, the others don't even matter anymore. You just look at it as if it was a number, when in reality it isnt, it's a string.

Comment: Ok, got the idea! Can you give me some guidance to fix that issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: when sorting by name, strings are fine, because you expect said behavior. However, when sorting by price, you should compare as numbers. You could convert the price to a number before comparing. Imho it is maybe not a good idea to store a price as a string to begin with. A price is a number afterall, you will just run into similar problems when you try to operate on the price and notice that `"10" + 5 === "105"`